# Changing caption of a dynamically created Command Button

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform that has fifty or so frames on it (the number changes each time it generated). Inside each frame is a label, 2 checkboxes, a command button and a textbox. Everything but the userform itself is dynamically created and named sequentially .

```
Dim ColEvents2 As Collection
Dim ColEvents3 As Collection
Dim ColEvents4 As Collection
Dim ColEvents5 As Collection
Dim DynamicFrames As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim colCount As Long
    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim leftMargin As Long
    Dim topMargin As Long
    Dim frameWidth As Long
    Dim frameHeight As Long
    Dim gap As Long
    Dim formWidth As Long
    Dim formHeight As Long

' Set references to the worksheet and calculate the last row with data
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formatting")
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row

Set DynamicFrames = New Collection

' Initialize variables for layout
rowCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(lastRow / 8, 0)
colCount = 8
leftMargin = 10
topMargin = 5
frameWidth = 150
frameHeight = 100
gap = 5

' Calculate the size of the UserForm based on the number of frames
formWidth = leftMargin + (frameWidth + gap) * colCount + 15
formHeight = topMargin + (frameHeight + gap) * rowCount + 30

' Set UserForm size
Me.Width = formWidth
Me.Height = formHeight

' Loop through the data and create frames, labels, checkboxes, checkboxes 2, commandbuttons and textboxes
For row = 1 To rowCount
    For col = 1 To colCount
        Dim frame As Object
        Dim label As Object
        Dim CheckBox As Object
        Dim CheckBox2 As Object
        Dim CommandButton As Object
        Dim textBox As Object
        
        ' Calculate the current cell's index
        Dim cellIndex As Long
        cellIndex = (row - 1) * colCount + col + 1
        
        ' Check if the current cell index is within the data range
        If cellIndex <= lastRow Then
        
            ' Create a new frame
            Set frame = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "Frame_" & cellIndex)
            With frame
                .Left = leftMargin + (col - 1) * (frameWidth + gap)
                .Top = topMargin + (row - 1) * (frameHeight + gap)
                .Width = frameWidth
                .Height = frameHeight
                .Caption = ""
            End With
            
            ' Add the frame to the DynamicFrames collection
            DynamicFrames.Add frame, "Frame_" & cellIndex
            
            ' Create a new label
            Set label = frame.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Label_" & cellIndex)
            With label
                .Left = 10
                .Top = 5
                .Width = frameWidth - 20
                .Font.Size = 10
                .Caption = ws.Cells(cellIndex, 2).value
                .TextAlign = 2
                If ws.Cells(cellIndex, 6).value = "1" Then
                    .ForeColor = RGB(0, 100, 0)
                Else
                    .ForeColor = &H80000012
                End If
            End With
            
            ' Create a new checkbox
            Set CheckBox = frame.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox_" & cellIndex)
            With CheckBox
                .Left = 10
                .Top = 30
                .Caption = "Col Filter"
                If ws.Cells(cellIndex, 4).value = "1" Then
                    .value = True
                Else
                    .value = False
                End If
            End With
            
                SetCheckClickEvent CheckBox
            
            ' Create a new second checkbox
            Set CheckBox2 = frame.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox2_" & cellIndex)
            With CheckBox2
                .Left = 75
                .Top = 30
                .Caption = "Date Filter"
                If ws.Cells(cellIndex, 6).value = "1" Then
                    .value = True
                Else
                    .value = False
                End If
            End With
            
                SetCheckClickEvent2 CheckBox2
            
            ' Create a new commandbutton
            Set CommandButton = frame.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "CommandButton_" & cellIndex)
            With CommandButton
                .Caption = "Format" & " " & ws.Cells(cellIndex, 5).value
                .Top = 50
                .Width = frameWidth - 70
                .Left = (frameWidth / 2) - (.Width / 2)
                .Font.Size = 8
                .Height = 20
            End With
            
                SetCommandClickEvent CommandButton
            
                ' Create a new textbox
            Set textBox = frame.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "TextBox_" & cellIndex)
            With textBox
                .Left = 10
                .Top = 75
                .Width = frameWidth - 20
                .Font.Size = 10
                .value = ws.Cells(cellIndex, 1).value
                If ws.Cells(cellIndex, 4).value = "1" Then
                    .Enabled = True
                    .BackColor = &H80000005
                Else
                    .Enabled = False
                    .BackColor = &H8000000F
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next col
Next row

' Add save button
Dim CommandButton2 As MSForms.CommandButton
Set CommandButton2 = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", , True)
With CommandButton2
    .Caption = "Save"
    .Width = 60
    .Height = 30
    .Left = Me.Width - .Width - 50 ' Adjust the position as needed
    .Top = Me.Height - .Height - 50 ' Adjust the position as needed
End With
            
SetCommandClickEvent2 CommandButton2
```

End Sub

I have a class module that holds all the event handlers.

```
    Public WithEvents CheckBox As MSForms.CheckBox
    Public WithEvents CheckBox2 As MSForms.CheckBox
    Public WithEvents CommandButton As MSForms.CommandButton
    Public WithEvents CommandButton2 As MSForms.CommandButton
    Public ParentForm As APICallNames
    
    Private Sub CommandButton_Click()
    
        Dim frameName As String
        frameName = Replace(CommandButton.Parent.Name, "CommandButton_", "Frame_")
        
        Dim CommandButtonName As String
        CommandButtonName = Replace(frameName, "Frame_", "CommandButton_")
        
        Dim frame As Object
        Set frame = CommandButton.Parent
        
        Dim CmdButton As Object
        On Error Resume Next
        Set CmdButton = frame.Controls(CommandButtonName)
        Set ParentForm.ClickedCommandButton = Me.CmdButton
        On Error GoTo 0

    Dim CMDCaption As String
    CMDCaption = CommandButton.Caption
    
    FormatTypesForm.InitializeForm CMDCaption
    
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub CheckBox_Click()
        Dim frameName As String
        frameName = Replace(CheckBox.Parent.Name, "CheckBox_", "Frame_")
        
        Dim textBoxName As String
        textBoxName = Replace(frameName, "Frame_", "TextBox_")
        
        Dim frame As Object
        Set frame = CheckBox.Parent
        
        Dim textBox As Object
        On Error Resume Next
        Set textBox = frame.Controls(textBoxName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If Not textBox Is Nothing Then
            If CheckBox.value = True Then
                textBox.Enabled = True
            textBox.BackColor = &H80000005
        Else
            textBox.Enabled = False
            textBox.BackColor = &H8000000F
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()

    Dim frameName As String
    frameName = Replace(CheckBox2.Parent.Name, "CheckBox2_", "Frame_")
    
    Dim labelName As String
    labelName = Replace(frameName, "Frame_", "label_")
    
    Dim frame As Object
    Set frame = CheckBox2.Parent
    
    Dim label As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set label = frame.Controls(labelName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not label Is Nothing Then
        If CheckBox2.value = True Then
            label.ForeColor = RGB(0, 100, 0)
        Else
            label.ForeColor = &H80000012
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

APICallNames.SaveControlValuesToWorksheet

End Sub
```

I have a second userform that the user choices what the caption of the calling command button from the first userform should be.

```
Public Sub InitializeForm(CMDCaption As String)
    Dim RevCMDCaption As String
    RevCMDCaption = CMDCaption
    
    If RevCMDCaption = "Format 1" Then
        TbN0.value = True
    ElseIf RevCMDCaption = "Format 2" Then
        TbN2.value = True
    ElseIf RevCMDCaption = "Format 3" Then
        TbText.value = True
    ElseIf RevCMDCaption = "Format 4" Then
        TbSD.value = True
    ElseIf RevCMDCaption = "Format 5" Then
        TbLD.value = True
    ElseIf RevCMDCaption = "Format 6" Then
        TbDol.value = True
    ElseIf RevCMDCaption = "Format 7" Then
        TbN7.value = True
    End If
    
    Me.StartUpPosition = 0
    Me.Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * Me.Width)
    Me.Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * Me.Height)
    
    Me.Show
    
End Sub

Private Sub CbSave_Click()

    Dim FormatSent As String

    If TbDol.value = True Then
        FormatSent = "Format 6"
        CMDCaption = FormatSent
    ElseIf TbLD.value = True Then
        FormatSent = "Format 5"
        CMDCaption = FormatSent
    ElseIf TbN0.value = True Then
        FormatSent = "Format 1"
        CMDCaption = FormatSent
    ElseIf TbN2.value = True Then
        FormatSent = "Format 2"
        CMDCaption = FormatSent
    ElseIf TbN7.value = True Then
        FormatSent = "Format 7"
        CMDCaption = FormatSent
    ElseIf TbSD.value = True Then
        FormatSent = "Format 4"
        CMDCaption = FormatSent
    ElseIf TbText.value = True Then
        FormatSent = "Format 3"
        CMDCaption = FormatSent
    End If
    
    Me.Hide

End Sub
```

I have not been able to get the selected option from the second userform to update the caption of the calling command button from the first userform. I know I am not passing the variable/object correctly. How do you pass a variable/object from the event handler to the initialize sub then have the save sub pass back another variable/object to the event handler in class module?

Comment: Can you show the code calling the second userform?

Comment: General advice: Treat both userforms as classes. That means: deliberately instantiate both of them at the right moment, add properties to both of them to communicate with them. Get their choices from them when their OK button was clicked by reading the properties involved, things like that.

Comment: The code calling the second userform is in the class module (APICallNames) above  `FormatTypesForm.InitializeForm CMDCaption`. In the InitializeForm sub is the `.show`

Comment: I don't want both form loading every time. The second userform is only used to select the formatting type of a column on a report sheet. It will seldomly be used so I only need it to be available on demand.

Comment: If I correctly understand your code, I'd go adding "CommandButton.Caption=CMDCaption" right after "FormatTypesForm.InitializeForm CMDCaption"

Comment: But I'd strongly recommend you following @jkpieterse piece of advice.
Your code is already instantiating object of your UserForm classes (like, I guess, FormatTypesForm and  APICallNames), but you're not aware of it and hence you cannot control them properly. To say the least you might be generating userform instances you0d hardly want to be there!

Comment: Thank you user3598756, that put me on the right track to get it working. See answer below.

Comment: @Hareborn, seeing no answer: please add it so as to help future readers

Comment: I added the answer, sorry got called away in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

I add this to my class module

```
FormatTypesForm.InitializeForm CMDCaption, CMDButton

CommandButton.Caption = CMDCaption
```

Then altered my InitializeForm & Save sub in the second userform to

```
Private Sub CbSave_Click()
   
    Me.Hide

End Sub

Public Sub InitializeForm(CMDCaption As String, CMDButton As Object)
    Dim RevCMDName As String
    RevCMDName = CMDCaption

If RevCMDName = "Format 1" Then
    TbN0.value = True
ElseIf RevCMDName = "Format 2" Then
    TbN2.value = True
ElseIf RevCMDName = "Format 3" Then
    TbText.value = True
ElseIf RevCMDName = "Format 4" Then
    TbSD.value = True
ElseIf RevCMDName = "Format 5" Then
    TbLD.value = True
ElseIf RevCMDName = "Format 6" Then
    TbDol.value = True
ElseIf RevCMDName = "Format 7" Then
    TbN7.value = True
End If

Me.StartUpPosition = 0
Me.Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * Me.Width)
Me.Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * Me.Height)

Me.Show

If TbDol.value = True Then
    CMDCaption = "$.$$"
ElseIf TbLD.value = True Then
    CMDCaption = "Long Date"
ElseIf TbN0.value = True Then
    CMDCaption = "0"
ElseIf TbN2.value = True Then
    CMDCaption = "0.00"
ElseIf TbN7.value = True Then
    CMDCaption = "0.0000000"
ElseIf TbSD.value = True Then
    CMDCaption = "Short Date"
ElseIf TbText.value = True Then
    CMDCaption = "Text"
End If
```

End Sub

The class module calls the InitializeForm sub in the second userform which contains the `Me.Show`. So I altered the save function to just run the `Me.Hide` which automatically goes back to the InitializeForm sub to finish running. Since the user by this put has already made their selection from the toggle buttons, I just captured it's caption then and reset the original variable CMDCaption. This is passed back to event handler and updates the corresponding command buttons caption as needed.